# timthumb NOT_FOUND_IMAGE resize

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, wordpress-theming, timthumb

In a wordpress site, i have defined a default NOT_FOUND_IMAGE in timthumb config file:

```
// "http://example.com/timthumb-config.php".
<?php 
if(! defined('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE') ) define ('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE', 'http://example.com/img/default.jpg');
```

Is there any way to force resizing of this image depending on timthumb request parameters. For instance:

```
// 404 occurs
timthumb.php?src=http:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimg%2F404-image.jpg&h=180&w=120
// get resized (cropped) default image
timthumb.php?src=http:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fimg%2Fdefault.jpg&h=180&w=120
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if (!defined('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE'))
  define ('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE','images/ingredient.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't rate `timbthumb`, and I think it has security issues. Install and use the [ThumbGen plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thumbgen/) instead.

You can then use it really easily with a normal editable conditional php statement.. (Pseudo)

```
<?php if you have a thumbnail { 
       Output the img with thumbgen resized
} else {
       Output the no image, you can even use thumbgen if you want
}
?>
```

Real world example:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
        {
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $alt_text = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');  
        $image_url = $image_url[0];
        ?>

            <img src='<?php thumbGen($image_url,175,175, "crop=1"); ?>' />

        <?php
        }

    else
        {
        ?>

            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/no-photo.png" alt="No Photo!">

        <?php
        }
?>
```

Comment: i need to handle 404 "not found image" error, with the same timthumb request parameters, specially **h={height}&w={width}**. I just can't use a "featured image" conditional handling. Thanks!